Usage of .net syntax in python
I'm trying to translate a programm written in .net to python. I'm using clr and pythonnet
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.IO")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")

from System.Reflection import Assembly
from System import String, Func, Action, Array, Int32
from System.IO import FileInfo
from System.Drawing import Point

which will be imported correctly
Further I've imported a dll in the following way:
dll_path = os.path.abspath("Flir.Atlas.Cronos.7.5.0/lib/net452/Flir.Atlas.Image.dll")
os.environ['PATH'] += ";%s"%os.path.dirname(dll_path)

clr.AddReference(dll_path)
assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll_path)

clr.AddReference("Flir.Atlas.Image")
import Flir.Atlas.Image as ft

Now I try to read from the ft with the following, correct syntax:
location = Point (X, Y) 
ft.ThermalImage.GetValueAt(location)

where Point is imported as above mentioned. X and Y are the position. But it is not accepted. I get an typeerror:
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for ThermalImage.GetValueAt: ()
From the SDK docs I have only this information:

GetValueAt()
ThermalValue Flir.Atlas.Image.ThermalImage.GetValueAt     (Point  location)
Gets a ThermalValue from a position in the Thermal Image.
Parameters:
location: A point that specifies the location for the value to read.
Returns:
The ThermalValue including value and stateThermalValue.

As direct parameters are not accepted I tried to make a function which return a Point object:
def position():
    pos = Point (measurement.X, measurement.Y)
    return pos

which returns <System.Drawing.Point object at 0x00000219AC97DA40>
and give it directly to the call
x = ft.ThermalImage.GetValueAt(location)

and got

TypeError: No method matches given arguments for ThermalImage.GetValueAt: ()

How can I pass the position correctly to the .GetValueAt(position) call?

Are you sure it's System.Drawing.Point?

Maybe it's wrong, but I have no other idea. I've tried other system.dll's but got same result. Maybe the import is wrong, gut other calls work.
